# C++11 - Program cuts off first letter of every input [Using: cin.ignore and getline)

Tags: c++, c++11

Good day!
I was wondering why my program (Written in C++11) keeps cutting off the first character of every user input.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  ofstream dataFile;
  dataFile.open("studentData.txt");

  string set1, set2, set3, set4;

cout << "How long was the fish when you first measured it?" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, set1);
dataFile << set1 << endl;

cout << "How long is the fish now?" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, set2);
dataFile << set2 << endl;

cout << "Where was the fish when you first tagged it?" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, set3);
dataFile << set3 << endl;

cout << "Where is the fish now?" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, set4);
dataFile << set4 << endl;

dataFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Here is the output if the input is as follows:
set1 - 12 inches
set2 - 24 inches
set3 - Valdosta, Georgia
set4 - Miami, Florida

```
2 inches
4 inches
aldosta, Georgia
iami, Florida
```

Why is this happening? I've read up on using cin.ignore and cin.getline, however, I am unable to find a proper solution. Is it my syntax? Am I improperly using the functions?
Please bear in mind I am a beginner to programming in C++! ^^

-- Thanks!

Comment: It's because the shown code mixed together both `std::getline` and formatted input operations with the `<<` operator; and using `ignore()` is not a universal solution. Unless you fully understand the interactions between the two, surprising results like this can happen. Until you fully understand how they work, either use only `std::getline`, or only the `<<` operator to read input.

Comment: Right off the bat: `cin.ignore();
getline(cin, set1);` What is there to ignore but the very first input character?

Comment: Get rid of the calls to `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- those `<<` operators are output, not input. They don't affect the input operations.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the calls to `cin.ignore()`, because it's ignoring your first character. The following code worked for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

    int main() {

      ofstream dataFile;
      dataFile.open("studentData.txt");

      string set1, set2, set3, set4;

    cout << "How long was the fish when you first measured it?" << endl;
    getline(cin, set1);
    dataFile << set1 << endl;

    cout << "How long is the fish now?" << endl;
    getline(cin, set2);
    dataFile << set2 << endl;

    cout << "Where was the fish when you first tagged it?" << endl;
    getline(cin, set3);
    dataFile << set3 << endl;

    cout << "Where is the fish now?" << endl;
    getline(cin, set4);
    dataFile << set4 << endl;

    dataFile.close();

    return 0;
    }
```